# How to link multiple C++ cmake project to a Android Studio/gradle project?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have two separate native C++ project built with NDK and using in a single Android application. I have linked one of them to the project in Android project via right click and select "Link C++ Project with Gradle".
[image: Link C++ Project with Gradle]

This operation added following text to *build.gradle*.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}
```

How can I added another one to the application? Note I cannot merge those two C++ project. I want to debug C++ code in Android Studio, not just compile it.

Environment: Android Studio 3.4, gradle-4.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link them to two library modules instead and add this there twice:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = ["src/main/cpp"]
    }
}
```

so it will load two different `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand this now. You are correct.

Comment: I wish I'd understand it. What is them, this, there?

Comment: Copy this to there so that that points to this which therefore brings that... instead of this. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You can do such thing below:

```
Project1/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
Project2/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

The root `CMakeLists.txt` should contain code like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
add_subdirectory(Project1)
add_subdirectory(Project2)
```

`cmake` will automatically recurse every project that is indicated in the root `CMakeLists.txt`